# DIV extending beyond parent DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to keep a child DIV from extending over the parent....the DIV in question is the one seen below labeled with id="2".....it goes past the parent DIV and goes all the way to the bottom of the page/browser window.  I've modified the height, adding padding, changed location of the DIV and nothing works....not sure what to try next:

```
<div id="2" style="width:15%; height:90%; padding:10px; background-color:#2A7FAA; float:right; margin-top:200px"></div>

<div style="background-color:#FFF; border:thick; border-width:thick;">
  <div style="margin-left:250px;">

    <img style="padding:2em;" alt="ASH Banner" src="images/banner.png" class="banner"> <img style="padding:2em;" alt="ASH Banner" src="images/dsh-logo.png" class="logo">
  </div>
</div>

<div style="height:15px; background-color:#2A7FAA"></div>

<div style="margin-left:150px; background:#CCC">

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" style="background-color:transparent">HOME 
        </button>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" style="background-color:transparent">PERSONNEL 

        </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" style="background-color:transparent">INSURANCE 
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" style="background-color:transparent">WORKERS COMP 
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" style="background-color:transparent">EMPLOYMENT<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" style="background-color:transparent">BENEFIT PREMIUMS<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<hr / style="border-width: 2px; width:800px; margin-right:9em;">


<div style="margin-top:3em">
  <div style="width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <p>Text Goes Here Text Goes Here Text Goes Here</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div class="cbox" style="left: 320px; top: 150px; width: 622px;">
    <table>


      <tr>
        <td><img class="center" alt="" src="images/sponsor-dot.gif" width="15" />&nbsp;<span onClick="openClose('a1')" style="cursor:hand; cursor:pointer; color: #33F; text-decoration:underline">Personnel Contacts</span>
          <div id="a1" class="texter">
            <ul class="style3">
              <li class="listbox"><a href="user_area/hr/PERSONNEL%20DEPARTMENT%20phone%20list.pdf">Personnel Phone List</a></li>
              <li class="listbox"><a href="User_Area/hr/PAYROLLPARTNERS.pdf">Payroll Partners</a></li>
              <li class="listbox"><a href="User_Area/hr/PersonnelSpecialistWorkAssignments.pdf">Personnel Specialist Work Assignments</a></li>
              <li class="listbox"><a href="User_Area/hr/WORKAREABYPAYROLLREPORTINGUNIT.pdf">Work Area by Payroll Reporting Unit</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><img class="center" alt="" src="images/sponsor-dot.gif" width="15" />&nbsp;<span onClick="openClose('a2')" style="cursor:hand; cursor:pointer; color: #33F; text-decoration:underline">Insurance Information</span>
          <div id="a2" class="texter">
            <ul class="style3">
              <li class="listbox"><a href='User_Area/HR/BenefitsWorksheet2017.pdf'>Benefits Worksheet                                          </a></li>
              <li class="listbox"><a href='http://eservices.calhr.ca.gov/BenefitsCalculatorExternal/'>Benefit Premium Calculator                                  </a></li>
              <li class="listbox"><a href='http://www.calhr.ca.gov/employees/pages/new-employee-benefits-orientation.aspx'>New Employee Benefits Orientation </a></li>
              <li class="listbox"><a href='user_area/hr/HealthInsuranceMarketplaceCoverageOptions.pdf'>Health Insurance Marketplace Coverage Options               </a></li>
              <li class="listbox"><a href='user_area/hr/2018HighlightsAndChanges.pdf'>2018 Plan Highlights and Changes</a></li>
              <li class="listbox"><a href='user_area/hr/DentalHandbook2017.pdf'>Dental Handbook 2017</a></li>
              <li class="listbox"><a href='user_area/hr/DentalHandbook2018.pdf'>Dental Handbook 2018</a></li>
              <li class="listbox"><a href='user_area/hr/CobenHandbook2017.pdf'>COBEN Handbook 2017</a></li>
              <li class="listbox"><a href='user_area/hr/CobenHandbook2018.pdf'>COBEN Handbook 2018</a></li>
              <li class="listbox"><a href='user_area/hr/FlexElectHandbook2017.pdf'>Flex Elect Handbook 2017</a></li>
              <li class="listbox"><a href='user_area/hr/FlexElectHandbook2018.pdf'>Flex Elect Handbook 2018</a></li>
              <li class="listbox"><a href='user_area/hr/Open_Enrollment_Event_Flyer.pdf'>2017-18 Open Enrollment Event 9/11/17 12pm-2pm</a></li>
              <li class="listbox"><a href='user_area/hr/Open_Enrollment_Newsletter.pdf'>CalPERS 2017-18 Open Enrollment Newsletter</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td><img class="center" alt="" src="images/sponsor-dot.gif" width="15" />&nbsp;<span onClick="openClose('a14')" style="cursor:hand; cursor:pointer; color: #33F; text-decoration:underline">Employment</span>
          <div id="a14" class="texter">
            <ul class="style3">
              <li class="listbox"><a href="http://www.dsh.ca.gov/video/Training_and_Experience_Assessment_Instructions.wmv">Training and Experience (T&E) Assessment Instructions</a></li>
              <li class="listbox"><a href="https://jobs.ca.gov/pdf/STD678.pdf">Examination/Employment Application</a></li>
              <li class="listbox"><a href="User_Area/Jobs/EXAM%20ANNOUNCEMENT.pdf">Exam Announcements</a></li>
              <li class="listbox"><a href="User_Area/Jobs/VACANCY%20LISTING.pdf">Vacancy Listings</a></li>
              <li class="listbox"><a href="pdf/pml.pdf">CalHR Best Hiring Practices</a></li>
              <li class="listbox"><a href="pdf/AT2060.pdf">Authorization to Obtain Employment Reference Information</a></li>
              <li class="listbox"><a href="pdf/AT2061.pdf">Pre-Employment Reference Checklist</a></li>

            </ul>

          </div>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: div with id="a2" or with id="2". Not able to see any with id = 2 though

Comment: The div with id="2" has no parent element.

Comment: try removing float="right". Dont know actually what is your code and what you want to explain but the misbehavior can possibly be because of float because float will make the div to loose height and every next element would wrap around it.

Comment: Did my answer solve anything? If not I will remove it.

Comment: Hi guys - thanks for replying....accidentally cut off my code at the top.  Here's what I have....don't see a missing DIV, plus I do have the body tag:

Comment: <body>

<div id="1" style="width: 1175px; margin-top:1em; background-color:#C1F1FF; border:2px solid;">